# Add Size in Elastic NativeSearchQuery

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

```
        final QueryBuilder contentTagQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .filter( QueryBuilders.termQuery("tenantId" , "en"));

        SearchHits<Content> searchHits =
                elasticsearchOperations.search(
                        new NativeSearchQuery(contentTagQuery), Content.class,
                        IndexCoordinates.of("index"));
```

How can I add size in this query, as I only need the first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this on the `Query` instance:

```java
NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQuery(contentTagQuery);
query.setMaxResults(1);
```

Comment: @p-j-meisch , How can we add a timeout in our nativesearchquery ?? I am trying below code, but its giving error.   NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQuery(contentTagQuery);
            searchQuery.setMaxResults(1);
            searchQuery.setTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(450L));